# Sitecore Azure 9.1 Marketing Operations service error

Tags: xconnect, marketing-automation, paas

I'm receiving this error in my Sitecore 9.1 `Azure Marketing Operations service`.

FYI my `xCollect` service is pointing to `MongoDB` instance so I have enabled `sc.Xdb.Collection.Data.MongoDb.xml` in `xCollect/Search` services.

The Sitecore 9.1 installation guide suggests to only enabled `MongoDB` in above 2 services.

But wondering based on the error, do I need to enabled the same `MongoDB` xml file in my Marketing Operations service as well?

Not sure if the error is tied up to that.

Anyone else seen this error?

Any help will be appreciated!

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This configuration has not been initialized. Please call the initialize method before using it.,
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.CheckInitialized(),
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.get_CurrentModel(),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)",
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)",
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)",
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider),
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.c__DisplayClass15_0.b__1(IServiceProvider provider),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)",
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)",
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)",
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)",
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope),
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider),
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.ServiceConfiguration.get_Engine(),
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.Program.RunAsConsoleApp(),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with incorrect messaging connection string in the Marketing Operations. Correcting that connection string fixed it.